# leaving unused use statements in php

Tags: php, symfony

In symfony2 when I use console to generate a controller, symfony2 imports some classes using use statement, which sometimes I don't use in the actual code, for example:

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
```

what is the impact of leaving them, should I delete them.

I just don't tend to delete them, in case I needed them in later phase.

Comment: are used in the annotations if you choice  configuration annotation type

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having unused `use` statements in PHP doesn't impact performance. At least not in any noticeable measure.

Two statements you mention, however are used. They are used for annotation routing, eg:

```
<?php

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class MyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/some/route")
     */
    public function someAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

So if you are using them in annotations, you'll need them. If you aren't you can safely remove them.

You can technically use annotations without those use statements too but it looks terribly ugly:

```
<?php

class MyController
{
    /**
     * @Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route("/some/route")
     */
    public function someAction()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

#### If you are using PHPStorm

If you are using PHPStorm IDE, you can install **PHP Annotations** plugin. It will recognize them and mark those two statements as **used** if you use them through annotations.

Comment: Thank you Igor, and yes I am using PHPStorm with Symfony2 plugin, I'll try the PHP Annotations plugin.

Comment: If you don't use theses annotations should should indeed delete the use statement. Saying: "I just don't tend to delete them, in case I needed them in later phase" is generally a bad idea. If you need them later, just copy/paste from another controller.

Comment: A "use" only tells PHP to actually "use" e.g. "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route" instead of "Route" given inside the code. It's a simple replacement for the interpreter.